# Syntax Coloring for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, terminal, text-coloring

I started using Haskell today and am following the tutorial through learnyouahaskell.com. However, in the tutorial all of their syntax automatically gets colored in the terminal. I am using Command Prompt through ConEmu and was wondering if there was any way that I could also get this coloring (easily). I've been looking for downloads or suggestions online and couldn't find anything. I have Notepadd++ for when I want to make .hs files, but nothing for the terminal itself once I initialize ghci.

Comment: `Terminal` will not color your scripts. Only the editors (console versions too) can do that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using Emacs with [`haskell-mode`](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode). I'm a Emacs fan, and I just started exploring Haskell too, `haskell-mode` works perfectly. I don't know if there is something like this for Notepad++.

---

Here is [full list of editors](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Editors) that support Haskell highlighting. As for terminal colouring, I doubt that it will be easy on Windows (you're on windows, right?), you need an IDE.